# React Native - Android -InputText touch issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native android small application that now contains all the login / forgot password flow. In both components of login and set new password i have 2 inputText elements that implementing the suitable form. However, in both components i got an issue with writing text into the text input. It requires more than 2 taps (in randomize places of the inputText) so i'll be able to enter my text. I tried to find similar issues but it seems that no one actually experienced it. Here is the example of set new password -

```
  <View>
    <Image
        style={styles.***}
        source={{uri: '***'}}
    />
    <Text style={styles.resetTitle}>RESET PASSWORD</Text>
    <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>
      {this.renderError()}
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={this.updatePassword1}
      />
    </View>
    <Text style={placeholderStylePass1}>New Password</Text>
    <View style={styles.view}>  
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput}
        password={true}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={this.updatePassword2}
      />
    </View>  
    <Text style={placeholderStylePass2}>Confirm New Password</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updateNewPassword} style=   
                                               {styles.touchable} >
      <Image 
          style={styles.submit}
          source={{uri: '***'}}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

What can be the reason for that touching on inputText issue? How should i fix it? Thnx in advance..

Comment: I had a similar case because of keyboard. For example, if you have focused your first input and keyboard becomes active, when you try to focus your second input by tapping it (with open keyboard), keyboard will be closed first and only the second tap will focus the second input. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: sounds like we do not have the same problem. My is more complex i guess because it requires more than 2 taps for the keyboard to get open. somehow the cursor doesn't "get cought" on the inputText (both). for your problem maybe you will find solution here (i didnt research too much but it talks about keyboard issues)    https://blog.brainsandbeards.com/react-native-keyboard-handling-tips-a2472b74c114#.kt81jkevb

Comment: Maybe you have some styles issues? Something is covering a focus area of the inputs or maybe inputs are too small for a tap. I wonder if you have the same problem on the empty page. Other than that your code looks fine to me, it would be great if you could share the styles too. Do you use the latest RN 0.36 btw?